# Matcher in java, matcher behavior in a while loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, matcher

I'm reading a file that has this kind of pattern: `(section1, section2, section3) ...` But the format is not guaranteed, which means I have to handle cases like one section on separate lines, many sections on one line. And I also need to store each token's offset. So I'm running code like this, using Matcher because it gives offsets and tokens:

```
`define a global matcher
 while() {
    readSection1(matcher, other parameters);
    readSection2(matcher, other parameters);
    readSection3(matcher, other parameters);
}
```

You can see that I'm trying to pass this matcher so I can start from where I stopped. But now I have a problem. After my last readSection3 method ended, I tested that my matcher didn't hit the end, so I started a new round of reading.
However when I entered the while loop again, and pass the matcher to my readSection1 method, the matcher suddenly hit the end! Why would that happen?

I also run a little test:

```
String loop = "a b c d e f g h i j k l";
Matcher loopMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\S+").matcher(loop);
boolean loopEnded = false;
while (!loopEnded) {
use(loopMatcher);
    if (loopMatcher.hitEnd()) {
        loopEnded = true;
    }   
}

public static void use(Matcher matcher) {
  if (!matcher.find()) {
     System.out.println("loop not ended but matcher hit end");
  }   
}
```

it prints the error message too. Why?!

Okay, weird thing happens, now I run this little program again, the error is gone, but it's still in my big program.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that the `Matcher.hitEnd()` method returns true if the last string found by the matcher is at the end of the input. So if you have characters after the last section of your file, `Matcher.hitEnd()` will return false, even if it is actually the last section.

However, I ran your test code and it didn't display the error message. Are you sure that you posted the same code as your test ? The matcher you uses is not the one you initialized first ('loopMatcher' vs 'matcher').

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain this well. I'm actually operating on lines using a Scanner, not really there is a class Section. And the pattern is S1, S2, S3,S1,S2,S3...When my readSection3() ends, I'm supposed to go into next loop and read next S1, if there is one. So if the last S3 and next S1 are on the same line, I'll need to start from where I stopped. That's why I'm passing my Matcher, because it was supposed to stay on the last token of the last S3. And when I go into next loop and call readSection1(), I call matcher.find(), that Matcher should find next token, which belongs to section1.

Comment: You are right there is typo in my code, it should run now. But wait, I try to run it again and now everything's good?????What??????I just fixed this with a global Matcher!!!What do I waste time fixing it for if it fixed itself after 40 minutes????

Comment: However if I don't use the fixed version, my other program still goes wrong...hmm, let me walk through this again.